# how to make a .CMD to start program with parameters?

Tags: cmd

I have a program. now i made a .cmd file that opens it with the parameters m 1000.
The 1000 is a relation number of a customer in the database. now what i want to know if it is possible to make the 1000 variable. so i can automaticly change that number to another customer of choice that i already specified in a .php file or .html.

i hope my question is clear.

Comment: you mean for batch(.bat) file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on windows? Sorry if i don't get it, but you're tring to modify that cmd so if you run command.cmd 2000 it will run the program with m 2000? Have have a look at

http://www.horstmann.com/bigj/help/windows/advanced.html

there go to "Batch File Arguments" section so you can reuse the cmd command inside the cmd

Comment: well i have a programm a .exe which the .cmd file runs with the parameters 'm 1000' so that when the program runs it will start with the information on the customer with ID 1000. but what i want is to make that 1000 variable. So i make a .php file where i make a link that runs the .cmd file. In the .php file i specify the ID which it gets from a database now i want to automaticly make that ID appear in the .cmd file i created to start the .exe. So i wont have to keep changing the .cmd file manually.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, you need to run the cmd via php or edit it via php and run manually?

Comment: Edit via PHP and run the cmd manually so i can then make a hyperlink in MS Outlook to the CMD file so i cam email it to someone so he can open it the program with his own ID because MS Outlook doesnt support hyperlinks which use parameters

Comment: i just wanna make the 1000 (CustomerID) variable wether i can change it using php or that the .cmd file asks for ID input and then automaticly changes the URL to open the .exe file doesnt matter

Comment: Well if the cmd is just something like:

`prog.exe m 2000`

use php this way:

`<?php
$id = 1000;
file_put_contents('file.cmd',"prog.exe m $id");
?>`

Comment: oke thnx alot that was what i was looking for im srry if i was confusing about what i wanted